# XSLT loaded with AJAX, contains <script> fired only in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, xslt, xhtml

I write an application where AJAX loads an XSLT which has a `<script>` inside.

The strange thing is that script runs in Firefox without `eval()`. Script is not ran in Opera or Chrome.
So, I simplify the code and I post it here.

Is it a Firefox bug?

Is there a cross-browser workaround? (A workaround which does not run `eval()` on firefox, only for scripts from xslt, but run `eval()` on Chrome, Opera for every script loaded with AJAX - both in XSLT or in XHTML).

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><script src="app.js" /></head>
<body onload="locationHashChanged();" />
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
function get(file) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", file, false);
    request.send();
    return request.responseXML;
}

function insert(where, root) {
    //var scripts = root.getElementsByTagName('script');
    where.parentNode.replaceChild(root, where);
    //for(var z = 0; z != scripts.length; z++) eval(scripts[z]);
}

function locationHashChanged() {
    var xml = get('apps.xml');
    var xslt = get('xslt.xsl');
    var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslt);
    insert(document.body, xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document).firstChild);
};
```

**xslt.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> 

<xsl:template match="//*[@path='']">
<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script>alert('Only in Firefox');</script>
</body>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**apps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu name="" path="" />
```

Comment: Can you explain clearly which behaviour you get and which one you expect? Why do you mention `eval`, why is there code commented out using `eval`?

Comment: I get `alert()` only in Firefox. I expect nothing because ALL scripts loaded with AJAX need `eval()` to run. There is no `eval()` in this code.

Comment: The HTML5 spec http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#scriptTagXSLT has some non-normative text that explicitly distinguishes `script` elements created by `transformToFragment` from ones created otherwise. Based on that section I think Mozilla is right in executing the script code created by XSLT when the fragment is inserted into the browser window's document. It has nothing to do with AJAX or XMLHtttpRequest.

Comment: You are good! Yeap, it seems that all other browsers do it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to put the alert in a CDATA tag? So

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <![CDATA[alert('Only in Firefox');]]>
</script>
```

I've started doing that for all javascript that I include in xslt templates